# Standard layout type and reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, c++11, reinterpret-cast

Am I allowed to cast from my class to a structure if i have copied the members of the structure to my class?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

class Buffer
{
public:
    void * address;
    size_t size;

    Buffer(void * address = nullptr, size_t size = 0)
        : address(address), size(size)
    {
    }

    operator iovec *() const
    {
        // Cast this to iovec. Should work because of standard layout?
        return reinterpret_cast<iovec *>(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not const-correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you cannot cast away constness:

> §5.2.10p2. The `reinterpret_cast` operator shall not cast away constness (§5.2.11). (...)

So you need at least to write that as

```
operator iovec const*() const
{
    return reinterpret_cast<iovec const*>(this);
}
```

or

```
operator iovec *()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<iovec *>(this);
}
```

On top of that, you need to have both `Buffer` and `iovec` be standard-layout types, and `iovec` cannot have an alignment stricter (i.e. larger) than `Buffer`.

> §5.2.10p7. An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`
>   if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout
>   types (§3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than
>   those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. (...)

You also need to be careful not to break the [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/46642): in general, you cannot use two pointers or references to different types that refer to the same memory location.